# Magento PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I have a problem within the magento checkout. With integrating Billsafe Payment plugin I get the  following error in checkout process:

```
HTTP-Error 500 (Internal Server Error):
```

The error log says:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/AwHh/PaymentFee/Helper/Data.php

Any Ideas?

The code of Data.php:

```
/**
 * Check if the extension is active
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isEnabled()
{
    return (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/active');
}

/**
 * Check if minimum fee amount, maximum fee amount or percentage rate is given
 * @return boolean
 */
public function hasFeeValues()
{
    $min = (bool)max(0, Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/min_fee_amount'));
    $max = (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/max_fee_amount');
    $rate = (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/relative_fee');
    return ($min || $max || $rate);
}

public function getFeeProductSku()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/sku');
}

/**
 * if item represents fee product
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product|Mage_Sales_Model_Item $product
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isFeeProduct($product)
{
    return ($product->getSku() == $this->getFeeProductSku());
}

public function setFeeProduct($feeProduct)
{
    $this->feeProduct = $feeProduct;
}

public function getFeeProduct()
{
    if (is_null($this->feeProduct)) {
        $this->feeProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $this->getFeeProductSku());
    }

    return $this->feeProduct;
}

public function hasFeeProduct()
{
    $feeProduct = $this->getFeeProduct();
    return ($feeProduct && 0 < $feeProduct->getId());
}

/**
 * Obtain the fee that is set for the current payment method
 * @return float
 */
public function getPaymentFee()
{
    if (!$this->isEnabled()) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getPayment()->hasMethodInstance()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // get the currently set payment method
    $payment_model = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();

    // check which methods are enabled for payment fee via backend
    $enabled_methods = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/payment_methods'));

    if (!$payment_model || !in_array($payment_model->getCode(), $enabled_methods)) {
        return 0;
    }

    // return fee if
    // (1) a payment method has been selected by the customer
    // (2) the selected payment method is enabled for payment fee via backend
    // (3) the payment method has a fee
    return (float)$payment_model->getFee();
}

/**
 * get quote item representing fee
 * 
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
 */
protected function getFeeQuoteItem()
{
    foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if ($this->isFeeProduct($item->getProduct())) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Computed amount of payment fee based on backend configuration
 * and grand total and attach it to fee product.
 */
public function getUpdatedFeeProduct($product=null, $grandTotal=null)
{
    if (!$product) {
        $product = $this->getFeeProduct();
    }
    $product->setName($product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
    if (!$grandTotal) {
        $quote      = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
        $feeAmount  = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $quoteItem) {
            if ($this->isFeeProduct($quoteItem->getProduct())) {
                $feeAmount = $quoteItem->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();
                continue;
            }
        }
        $grandTotal -= $feeAmount;
    }
    $min = max(0, Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/min_fee_amount'));
    $max = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/max_fee_amount');

    $rate = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment_services/paymentfee/relative_fee');
    //$product->setName($this->__('Payment fee'));
    if ($this->getFeeQuoteItem()) {
        $product->setTaxPercent($this->getFeeQuoteItem()->getTaxPercent());
    }

    // first, set payment fee to the price configured in backend
    $price = $max;

    // If set to zero, do not limit the final fee
    if (!$max) {
        $max = INF;
    }

    $product->setCheckoutDescription($this->formatPrice($price))
        ->setExceedsMaxAmount(false)
        ->setExceedsMinAmount(false);

    // calculate relative fee if given in backend
    if ($rate) {
        $price = $grandTotal * $rate / 100;

        if ($max < $price) {
            // calculated relative fee exceeds maximum charge 
            // -> use maximum charge
            $product->setCheckoutDescription($this->formatPrice($max));
            $product->setExceedsMaxAmount(true);
            $price = $max;
        } elseif ($price < $min) {
            // calculated relative fee is below minimum charge 
            // -> use minimum charge
            $product->setCheckoutDescription($this->formatPrice($min));
            $product->setExceedsMinAmount(true);
            $price = $min;
        } else {
            // calculated relative fee is between minimum and maximum charge
            // -> use calculated relative fee
            $msg = '%s (%s%% of Total %s)';
            $product->setCheckoutDescription($this->__(
                $msg,
                $this->formatPrice($price),
                $rate,
                $this->formatPrice($grandTotal)
            ));
            $msg = '%s %s (%s%% of Total %s)';
            $product->setName($this->__(
                $msg,
                $product->getName(),
                strip_tags($this->formatPrice($price)),
                $rate,
                strip_tags($this->formatPrice($grandTotal))
            ));
        }
    }
    $product->setPriceInclTax($price)
        ->setPrice($price)
        ->setFinalPrice($price);

    // Make sure fee product is "in stock"
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
    $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
    $stockItem->setManageStock(1);
    $stockItem->setQty(10000);
    $stockItem->save();

    return $product;
}

public function removeFeeFromQuote(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote)
{
    foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $quoteItem) {
        if ($this->isFeeProduct($quoteItem->getProduct())) {
            $quote->removeItem($quoteItem->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is custom module app/code/community/AwHh/PaymentFee/Helper/Data.php paste the content here so we can check the error ?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say you need to dump your cache directory, but like Meabed says, not much we can do without some more context.

Comment: It's actually part of the official Plugin from BILLSAFE ... The Code of the Data.php is:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Solution:
You propably didnt add the virtual article.

Go to your Adminarea, choose catalog -> manage article
add a new one and choose virtual article
give some name for it and make sure its activce and NOT visible
set the SKU to something and copy it. you need it later!
set price zero and stock at least 1
you can choose if you give it a higher stock or just one and turn of the stock management.
after saving go to system->configuration->paymenttypes and there you have to
paste the SKU you just copied into the field where it says some with SKU.

after all you have to clear your cache's and there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

A helper class extends extends `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`..

class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data`  does not extend varien_object so `getName()` function will genertae this error.

instead of call getname from helper class object.

use
`$model = getmodel('whatever')` and then call
`$model->getName()` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can **disable Billsafe** under Configuration  (System->Configuration->payment) (set Active: no )